# Arduino Part Needs Identified

Tags: hardware

[image: I do not know what part this is. I ordered an Arduino beginners kit and this part was not labeled. Please help!]

I do not know what part this is. I ordered an Arduino beginners kit and this part was not labeled. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is an MPU6050 Module 3 Axis Accelerometer Gyroscope Module for Arduino.

Learn more: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050

[image]